# How do I install Firefox as a snap?

Tags: firefox, snap

According to ["Firefox is the default browser for Linux users on Ubuntu, new snap format coming soon"](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2016/04/21/firefox-default-browser-for-linux-users-ubuntu-new-snap-format-coming-soon/) (Future releases, 2016-04-21), Mozilla will be packaging Firefox as a snap. But as of November 2017, `snap find firefox` returns no results.

Has this snap been released yet? If so, how do I install it?

Comment: There is one here https://github.com/liu-xiao-guo/firefox-snap but I doubt it is official, due to a lack of information. I have not tried or tested it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now the snap has been published you can obtain the snap via:-

```
snap install firefox
```

Alternatively search for Firefox in GNOME Software.

Comment: thanks! do you know of a public issue / repo where I can follow progress?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. It's coming soon though :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that my settings got lost at update to 76.0 and snap (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I solved this by copying my old settings from `/home/username/.mozilla` to replace `/home/username/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla`. Of course
 I made a backup first.

It took some time and I hate "snap" for this, whatever snap is?

Comment: You answer ends with a "?", please take it out or ask a new question concerning whatever it is... :)